# magento upgrade issue Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

After Upgrade 1.9.3 Unable to admin login getting below Error

```
Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.
```

Answer (score 2):

Clear browser cache and login to admin http://yourURL.com/admin

Not like below URL:

http://yourURL.com/index.php/admin/system_config/index/key/96ed1120b1085948c5c6d1c18930b5ea/

Comment: i have https in my url https://yourURL.com/admin i am trying this only

Comment: Whatever your site URL

Comment: that was not solution